# Non-type template parameter error ('x' is not a type)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am attempting to build an OS X version of my friend's QT application, which he has built on Windows and Linux. We are both using g++. I'm using gcc 4.2.1. Unfortunately I do not know what version he had used when he built the application (it was quite awhile ago).

Could anyone shed some light on why I am getting the error:

```
../../../src/dbapi/dbcore/node.h:24: error: 'dimensions' is not a type
```

when compiling the following code:

Node.h:

```
template<class T,const unsigned int dimensions>
class EXPORT_DBCORE Node : public Transform<T,dimensions>
{
public:
  Node( Id id,
        QString& name,
        QString& text = "",
        // ************** Offending line: ***************
        Vector<T,dimensions> position = Vector<T,dimensions>(),
        Quaternion<T> rotation = Quaternion<T>() )
    : Transform<T,dimensions>( position, rotation )
    , mId( id )
    , mName( name )
    , mText( text )
  {
  }

private:
  ...
};
```

Vector.h:

```
template<class T,const unsigned int dimensions>
class EXPORT_DBCORE Vector
{
public:
  //! Default Constructor
  Vector()
  {
    mpArray = new T[dimensions];
    for( int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++ )
    {
      mpArray[i] = 0;
    }
  }
...
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry if it was not clear which line was number 24. It's indicated by the "Offending line" comment in the Node.h excerpt.

Comment: Can you give us a hint as to which line in the code snippet is line 24?

Comment: Have you included the `Vector` header file in the `Node` header file? And why use your own vector class, when both Qt and the standard library have good working classes?

Comment: Is gcc 4.2.1 the most recent compiler you have? Maybe if you switch to a recent version of clang it will work or you'll get better error messages.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sorry it's not more clear. It's indicated with the asterisk-filled comment in my Node.h excerpt.

@JoachimPileborg Yes. I just left a lot of the file out. I didn't write this code, I'm not sure why this was done.

@bames53 Yes, but I will try other versions. It would be nice to know the root of the problem though. Is something being done wrong or is it just a compiler issue?

@BoPersson Not sure, I tried it without `const` and still got the same result.

Comment: BTW, I see QString here, which usually means you are using QT.  Don't use templates in conjunction with QT, it messes up the moc process.

Comment: @bames53 clang trunk rejects it for the same reason (see [DR 325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325)), GCC 4.4 and later accepts it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the standard actually says this code is ill-formed, see [core issue 325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325). The C++ grammar says that a comma in the template argument list for a default argument is parsed as starting the next function argument, so the problem is in the `= Vector<T, dimensions>()` bit of the code, so `dimensions` is taken as starting a new function parameter, not as part of the template-id.

GCC 4.4.0 was changed nearly five years ago (see [Bug 57](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57)) to accept the code, do you have a good reason to be using such an old release?

If you can't upgrade, you can workaround the bug by adding a typedef to Node:

```
typedef Vector<T, dimensions> VectorType;
```

Then using that:

```
  Node( Id id,
        QString& name,
        QString& text = "",
        VectorType position = VectorType(),
        Quaternion<T> rotation = Quaternion<T>() )
```

Technically only the default argument needs to use the typedef, but I would use it for the parameter declaration and the default argument.  In fact I almost always declare a typedef for any container type my classes use and then use that typedef in the class. That is often shorter and means if you change the container then you often only need to update the typedef, not every use of it.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I'm using the MacPorts 2.7 build, and the problem has been resolved.

I was using 4.2.1 because that's what comes bundled with Xcode. I figured that whatever came with Xcode would be the most stable for OS X development.

Comment: No, what comes with Xcode is the last version licensed as GPLv2. Apple won't ship a newer version for licensing reasons, not technical reasons or stability reasons.